# Twilio Whisper and Open VBX

Tags: twilio

I am a beginning programmer and am currently working with Twilio Client and Open VBX. I have a large cache of phone numbers (around 15) on marched.voice star currently. I want to move them over to Twilio and open vbx.

Is it possible to program Twilio to have whisper when you pick up, announcing a name of a "a school" or something along those lines?

I want to port my numbers from Marchex.voicestar to Twilio and the forward those numbers to my landlines that I have. My question is can I record "whispers" for each number and then store them on a server somewhere and then when someone calls a twilio number, that will forward to my landline and also activate the pre-recorded "Whisper" so when someone picks a landline up, they will hear the "whisper" and be able to speak to the caller.

Thank you for your help. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Php is my preferred language, I have done extensive research on the subject and need clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Yup, Twilio totally supports whisper.  Check out this HowTo article which will walk you through it:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-call-screening-and-recording

This article shows you how you can use the `<Say>` verb to say something to the caller, but you could just as easily substitute that with the `<Play>` verb if you want to play a recording to them.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using? i have about 70 number with twilio and that was the best decision that i did. Please find attached the way i use whisper in my functions.

This is the whisper function

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        twiml.say('Call From Fuel');
    //return 
    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

and this is how i call the whisper function when the person asnwer the call

```
dial.number({url: 'whisper',}, context.MY_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

Again this is on twilio function that uses nodejs